# Java 8 streams intermediary map/collect to a stream with 2 values

Tags: java, java-stream

Imagine that I have the following working lambda expression:

```
        Map<Field, String> fields = Arrays.stream(resultClass.getDeclaredFields())
            .filter(f -> f.isAnnotationPresent(Column.class))
            .collect(toMap(f -> {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                return f;
            }, f -> f.getAnnotation(Column.class).name()));
```

I would like to create a stream with 2 values before the filter statement. So I want to do a mapping but still keep the original value aside from it. I want to achieve something like this:

```
        this.fields = Arrays.stream(resultClass.getDeclaredFields())
            //map to <Field, Annotation> stream
            .filter((f, a) -> a != null)
            .collect(toMap(f -> {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                return f;
            }, f -> a.name()));
```

Is this possible with Java 8 streams? I have looked at collect(groupingBy()) but still without succes.

Comment: You can provide a map supplier.  This supplier can provide a Map which already has a couple of entries. BTW You can do `.peek(f -> f.setAccessible(true))`

Comment: Thanks for that one, I didn't know peek. I have something, I will post it in an answer, because comments really don't work for code.

Comment: It's `Stream<T>` and must therefore have 1 concrete type for `T` in the stream at any time. There is currently no magic in Java to help create such types on the fly by magically capturing values like `(f, a)`. But it's not an uncommon problem so maybe that changes in the future. Meanwhile, there are libraries that try to tackle that: http://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.5/org/jooq/lambda/tuple/Tuple.html

Comment: Yes, it would be really nice if a next Java version provided a solution for something like that. I like the jooq framework, but at the moment we don't have enough lambda functions to justify yet another library in our huge project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like a `Pair` that holds two values.  You can write your own, but here is some code that repurposes `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`:

```
     Map<Field, String> fields = Arrays.stream(resultClass.getDeclaredFields())
            .map(f -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(f, f.getAnnotation(Column.class)))
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null)
            .peek(entry -> entry.getKey().setAccessible(true))
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue().name()));
```

Comment: @GoGoris: what makes you think that this is less overhead?

Comment: Because I can skip the whole hashMap, so this will skip the hash generation for each entry of the HashMap.

Comment: @GoGoris: your first code snippet in your question creates exactly one `Map`, just like the code of this answer, but the original code does not need an `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` instance for each declared field. So why do you think that this is less overhead?

Comment: Ah the first one, yes you are right. I just wanted to see whether I could avoid isAnnotationPresent because I always heard that reflection is slow. But I now realize that it are probably string method lookups that have a performance impact and not something like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the entire operation in one go during the `collect` operation without the need of a pair type:

```
Map<Field, String> fields = Arrays.stream(resultClass.getDeclaredFields())
    .collect(HashMap::new, (m,f) -> {
        Column c=f.getAnnotation(Column.class);
        if(c!=null) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            m.put(f, c.name());
        }
    }, Map::putAll);
```

Still, to me it looks cleaner to separate the two operations which do not becong together:

```
Map<Field, String> fields = Arrays.stream(resultClass.getDeclaredFields())
    .collect(HashMap::new, (m,f) -> {
        Column c=f.getAnnotation(Column.class);
        if(c!=null) m.put(f,c.name());
    }, Map::putAll);

AccessibleObject.setAccessible(
    fields.keySet().stream().toArray(AccessibleObject[]::new), true);
```

This solution does iterate twice over the fields having the annotation, but since this performs only one security check rather than one check per field, it might still outperform all other solutions.

Generally, you shouldn’t try to optimize unless there really is a performance problem and if you do it, you should measure, not guess about the costs of the operations. The results might be surprising and iterating multiple times over a data set is not necessarily bad.

Comment: I did actually measure the performance: the for loop was the fastest and than came the Pair but the difference was negligable. The performance of this code is in my case quite important. This is why I don't want to replace the loop if it isn't more readable.

Comment: But sorry where the code will be used is not really important, my intention was "how can I do something like this in Java 8?".
Your input set me thinking, it seems indeed a little bit cleaner. II will try out the performance if I have some time!

Comment: Of course, the performance characteristics depend on the number of remaining fields after filtering. I only mentioned performance just for the case that this is driving the desire to do the operation in one iteration. If this answer is giving food for thoughts, it does its job ;^)

Answer (score 1):

@Peter Lawrey: I tried your suggestion with an intermediary map. It works now but it is not really pretty.

```
this.fields = Arrays.stream(resultClass.getDeclaredFields())
            .collect(HashMap<Field, Column>::new, (map, f) -> map.put(f, f.getAnnotation(Column.class)), HashMap::putAll)
            .entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null)
            .peek(entry -> entry.getKey().setAccessible(true))
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue().name()));
```